# Gedit Plugins 'grayed out' when clicked to activate (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, text-editors, plugins, gedit, application-launch

I have installed [Gedit 2.30.1](https://download.gnome.org/binaries/win32/gedit/2.30/) (32 bit) on Windows 10.

**Problem:** When I add *any* external plugin to gedit, I can see the plugin listed in the `preferences` option, but it gets *grayed out* when clicked.

**Example:** [The regex search plugin](http://tapioca-voip.sourceforge.net/regexsearch_gedit_plugin.tar.gz).

**Method of installation:** Unzip the plugin, move the `regexsearch.gedit-plugin` file and `regexsearch` directory to `G:\gedit\lib\gedit-2\plugins`.

Launch gedit-> edit menu-> preferences -> Plugins -> Click on regex search

**Observation:** Plugin gets grayed out. Fails to load.

**Message printed on cmd.exe:** (When launched from cmd.exe)

```
G:\gedit\bin>gedit.exe

G:\gedit\bin>G:\gedit\lib\gedit-2\plugins\commander\entry.py:607: GtkWarning: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
  """)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\gedit\lib\gedit-2\plugins\regexsearch\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from regexsearchinstance import RegexSearchInstance
  File "G:\gedit\lib\gedit-2\plugins\regexsearch\regexsearchinstance.py", line 4, in <module>
    import gtk.glade
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

** (gedit.exe:3412): WARNING **: Error loading plugin 'Regex Search'
```

What could be the problem?